# search specific word in the specific range of a found word in elastic search Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to used elastic search and Kibana. I want to write a new query to search in the document. The query is:

Want to search the specific keyword in a specific range of a found word in Kibana.

I have multiple documents of the patient reports. I want find the document which contains thyroid positive report.

For example:

1) The thyroid test might be positive.

2) The patient has thyroid positive.

3) The patient has a positive report of the thyroid.

4) she hasn't suffered from thyroid.

In the documents, there might be a possibility that the keyword "thyroid" and "positive" do not come with together.

In the above four examples, the first three documents have thyroid positive report.
So, I want to write a query which finds the keyword "thyroid" in the document next find the "positive" keyword in a specific range of keyword "thyroid".

Please help me to find the optimized query.
Thanks,

Comment: Add your mapping and sample data

Comment: sorry  @jaspreetchahal I am not able to understand what you are saying.

Comment: Can you post your index mapping(where data is stored). GET <index>/_mapping will give it and one or two sample documents GET <index>/_search. hope I am getting your issue correctly

Comment: Did you try a match_phrase_query with a great slop (like 5, to match 3th document) ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323773/2396392